# JSON RPC/RestFull Keil ARM

Tags: json, arm, keil

Does ARM Keil HTTP embedded server supports JSON RPC with cgx calls?

Does ARM Keil HTTP embedded server also supports RestFul with cgx calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to implement a real RestFul interface on the library version of the Keil HTTP webserver as you can't access the HTTP requests.

Probably with the source code variant you can accomplish this.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. yes make sense.